# Classes owning their objects

Tags: objective-c, oop, object, inheritance

Question:
     I understand that origin is an instance variable of the Rectangle class which has the XYPoint type. The origin instance variable has two other instance variables x and y. I don't understand clearly, what the if statement in the rectangle class does?

I believed that the if (! origin) means if the origin is not equal to zero then do the following... Is the origin equal to zero? if yes how is it equal to zero and how is it validated in the if (! origin) statement. In other words what does the if (! origin) statement do?

Is there an instance where the origin is equal to zero? if this occurs, how will my code respond? I know that without the if statement myPoint object will not retain its initial value.

I will also like to know why we used the class directive in rectangle class rather than import. What difference does it make. I also noticed that we didn't import the XYPoint header at the rectangle's implementation. I will be very grateful if anyone is willing to help. Thanks a lot in advance.

NB: Please take a look at my codes below.

---

*
    **XYPoint Class**

```
 #import <Foundation / Foundation.h>

 @interface XYPoint: NSObject

 @property int x, y;

 -(void) setX: (int) Xval andY: (int) yVal;
 @end
```

---

```
 #import "XYPoint.h"

 @implementation  XYPoint

 @synthesize x, y;

 -(void) setX: (int) Xval andY: (int) yVal
  { x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
  }
  @end
```

---

*
    **Rectangle Class**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class XYPoint;
@interface Rectangle: NSObject

-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;
@end
```

---

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle
{ 
 XYPoint *origin
}

 -(void) SetOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt
{
 if (! origin)
 origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
 origin.x = pt.x;
 origin.y = pt.y;
}

-(XYPoint *) origin
{
  return origin;
}
@end
```

---

```
Main

#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
  XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

  [myPoint setX: 100 andY: 200];
  myRect.origin = myPoint;

  NSLog (@"Origin at (%i, %i)" , myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y); 

  [myPoint setX: 50 andY: 75];

  NSLog (@"Origin at (%i, %i)" , myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);
}
@end
```

---

```
Origin at (100, 200)
Origin at (100, 200)
```

---

Comment: Can you explain what you think is happening

Comment: if (! origin) does`t means origin is not equal to zero. Means if origin does`t exist. Origin is a pointer than point to a Xpoint object, and the question is if origin does`t exist, create and make igual to pt, could be zero.

Comment: @OnikIV Thank you Onik IV. But origin exist as it is an instance variable of the rectangle class.

Comment: (You may want to catch up on the Objective-C development, or find newer tutorials. The `@synthesize` statement isn't needed (in most cases) since Xcode 4.4: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html.)

Comment: @Wain I think the if statement checks if the origin does not have a value of zero, it if doesnt, it initializes it to zero. I am not sure as it does not make sense to me...

Comment: @Uchenna: As Onik said: `origin` is a *pointer*. Before you alloc/init an object instance the pointer is NULL/nil/nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining an instance variable creates a pointer that can be used to reference an instance. It doesn't create an instance for you. So, initially there is no origin.

The if statement checks if the origin exists yet, and if not it creates a new one, then the code copies the values from the one passed in the parameter.

Aside: Ideally the point class would be immutable and implement copying so rather than repeatedly creating new instances and updating them you can just copy the passed parameter. Copying would do nothing (return self) in the immutable class and is there only to support the addition of a mutable class in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When being declared an object instance variable is set to `nil` which is zero in terms of C / Objective-C.

To use an object it must be initialized. That's what the `if` statement checks and does

```
if (! origin) // alternative syntax if (origin == nil)
  origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
```

means

> if the object is `nil` initialize it. If not skip the line.

The `class` directive rather than the `import` statement is used when only the type of the class is mentioned in the code and the header file is not needed.
In your code the import statement is required if the classes are written in separate files.

PS: There are some lowercase / uppercase typos in your code and a semicolon is missing.